Is it better to use Aer simulator or a fake provider?
Does the fake provider mimic all the characteristics of the real backend (qubit connectivity, gate error, decoherence, noise)?
I want to execute a code that includes a Session.
Before running the code on the real backend, I want to test how the session would execute locally, hoping that the results would be similar to the results I would get when using the real backend.
I read somewhere that fake providers do not mimic noise of their corresponding real backend, and the use of Aer simulator while tuning its parameters to mimic a real backend was suggested. Somewhere else, I read that the fake providers mimic the noise of the real backend. I am a bit confused.
To get results similar to the ones I would get on a real backend, is it recommended to use a fake provider or Aer simulator?
Also, when running a session locally, would the session run or is it unable to execute locally?
